# Is data replicated to peer nodes in cassandra after increasing replication factor?

Tags: replication

I have a 8 node cluster running on DSE 4.5.1 with replication factor 2. I increased the replication factor to 3. Does it automatically replicate data to other cassandra nodes?

Comment: It should be doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is not replicated automatically, you need to run repair on all the nodes in the cluster. I would recommend you to run repair on one node at a time, this will reduce the load the cluster. Run nodetool repair -pr on every node.

During repair you will notice spike in CPU usage as this will trigger the compactions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll have to run a repair after deploying the change, for additional info see Datastax docs:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/update_ks_rf_t.html